# React navigation hook wont let me rediect cause its saying my screen doesnt exist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to navigate to a screen using react hook useNavigation but my app keeps saying

> Do you have a screen named 'Home'?

My app.js routes:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient} contextSharing={true}>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {!wasInitiated ? (
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Root}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          )}
  </QueryClientProvider>
</NavigationContainer>
```

and my login functionality that should redirect to "home" but it doesnt work for some reason..

```
const login = async (username, password, e) => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log(username);
console.log(password);
let response = await loginStep1(username, password, setFailedAttempt);
console.log("RESPONSE LOGIN: ", response);
let userAuthObj = {
  auth: response.auth,
  userId: response.user.id,
  username: response.user.username,
  userRoleId: response.user.role.id,
  userRoleName: response.user.role.name,
};
const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(userAuthObj);
AsyncStorage.setItem("auth", jsonValue);

if (response.user.validUser) {
  setUserAttemptingToLogin({
    userId: response.userId,
    username: response.username,
  });
}

navigate("Home");
```

};

Comment: do you have `const navigation = useNavigation()` set. as well as change `navigate("Home")` to `navigation.navigate("Home")`. give this a try

Comment: Yes I have tried both const navigation = useNavigation() and const { navigate } = useNavigation(); None of them works..

Comment: or maybe your `wasInitiated` i still false. after you get the user result, did you update `wasInitiated`?

Comment: This is my response from trying to use `navigation.navigate("Home")`  ` Do you have a screen named 'Home'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.`

Comment: With or without the wasInitiated check i still get the same error tho..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you don't have the home screen returned in you navigator, if you want to navigate based on a variable ( wasInitiated ) you should have 2 separate stack navigator and return them in the navigator like this:
;

```
import Auth from './AuthStack'
import App from './AppStack'

const MainNavigator = () => {
  const { wasInitiated } = fetchThisUsingReactQuery

  return (
 <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient} contextSharing={true}>
    <NavigationContainer>
      {wasInitiated ?
        <App />
        :
        <Auth />
      }
    </NavigationContainer>
  </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};

export default MainNavigator;
```

And then change the value of wasInitiaed in the login screen once the login attempt is successfull.

Comment: I just wrapped both parts in its own stack navigators but it still is asking me "Do you have s screen named 'Home'"

Comment: @Ara192 Don't use the navigate function to go to the Home screen, change the value of wasInitiaed in the login screen once the login attempt is successful

Comment: How do I set the value in the login screen(its other file) and directly get the updated value in app.js where im doing the check?

Comment: You're using React Query to wrap your navigator, use a global state variable. Learn about it from the docs here: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/overview